# Using MYSQL views in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, view

I want to create a view on MYSQL table and found the gem 
https://github.com/anykeyh/rails_db_views

but I did not understand how could I use it as I find the documentation not clear.
Where should I put this code in my project (which file and directory )

```
Rails.configure do |config|
  config.rails_db_views.views_path += %w( /some/view/path )
  config.rails_db_views.views_extension = "*.sql"

  config.rails_db_views.functions_path += %w( /some/function/path )
  config.rails_db_views.functions_extension = "*.sql"
end
```

I would be thankful if anyone told the full steps to use it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the README of the repo, you can place this inside an initializer.

Make a new file under `config/initializers/db_views.rb` and place the code there.